# jQuery load() function doesn't load everything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've been strugling with query for some time. I have a CMS that i want to use on my site, buy i cant use PHP includes so i decided to use jquery. I have made all the necesary includes and when i open the webpage it doesn't load all the files... Rarely does load() function load every file. Any ideas to solve the problem or alternatives? thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  
// find element with ID of "target" and put file contents into it  
$('#welcome-container').load('admin/data/blocks/Slider/Text.html');
$('#slides').load('admin/data/blocks/Slider/Imagini.html');  
$('#acasa-continut').load('admin/data/blocks/Acasa/Continut.html');  
$('#sidebar').load('admin/data/blocks/Sidebar/Continut.html');  
$('#sidebar-v1').load('admin/data/blocks/Sidebar/Video-1.html'); 
$('#sidebar-v2').load('admin/data/blocks/Sidebar/Video-2.html');
$('#principii').load('admin/data/blocks/Despre/Principii.html');
$('#echipa').load('admin/data/blocks/Despre/Echipa.html');
$('#echipament').load('admin/data/blocks/Despre/Echipament.html');
$('#contact-t').load('admin/data/blocks/Contact/Contact.html');
}); 
</script>
```

I have checked with deloper tools and it gives ,randomly on every refresh, 500 Internal Server Error on different elements

Comment: Use a slash before the resource. For example /admin/data/blocks/Slider/Text.html

Comment: What does the internal server error say ? I think these pages are not there or the path to these resources are wrong.

Comment: Are all of those elements present in the DOM before the first load? You might need to put loads that depend on other dynamic content inside callbacks.

Comment: you can check here to see exactly. http://www.hp-customs.ro/ I have changed the paths lik in the first comment, still the same problem. The paths are all ok, the files exist... i cant figure it out.. Any alternatives? P.S: its a repost, because its quite urgent and i didnt receive any answers. Thanks

Comment: An internal server error is an error on the server-side, not on the client-side. Therefore, jQuery has got nothing to do with it. Check your server-side code instead, and make sure you are not overloading/bombing your server.

Comment: Should it have something to do with cache?

Comment: 10 loads, that's 10 AJAX requests in rapid fire! Server settings may well disallow more than x simultaneous requests from the same IP address. If so then a variable number of failures is likely, depending on how quickly the requests get serviced. Why not make one AJAX request, serve all the data JSON-encoded then distribute it to the appropriate containers in a success handler? Even better, as the URLs are .html, I'm guessing the data is static, so why not just serve the page ready-made in the normal way?

Comment: Could you help me with a simple snippet?

Comment: I can show you what to do client-side. Server-side is another matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client-side code to request composite HTML and distribute it to the various containers will be something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $.ajax({
        url: 'admin/data/blocks/all/page.html',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
                $('#'+obj.target).html(obj.html);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This assumes `admin/data/blocks/all/page.html` to be a server-side resource that will deliver a json-encoded response of the following construction :

```
[
    { 'target':'welcome-container', 'html':'<div>whatever</div>' },
    { 'target':'slides', 'html':'<div>whatever</div>' },
    { 'target':'acasa-continut', 'html':'<div>whatever</div>' },
    { 'target':'sidebar', 'html':'<div>whatever</div>' },
    { 'target':'sidebar-v1', 'html':'<div>whatever</div>' },
    { 'target':'sidebar-v2', 'html':'<div>whatever</div>' },
    { 'target':'principii', 'html':'<div>whatever</div>' },
    { 'target':'echipa', 'html':'<div>whatever</div>' },
    { 'target':'echipament', 'html':'<div>whatever</div>' },
    { 'target':'contact-t', 'html':'<div>whatever</div>' },
]
```